# Recyclerview animation (layout change in size and margins after click)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-animation

Iam working on an app using `recyclerview` in which if I click an item, it will change in layout height(view will be visible) and margins changes.
How to animate like google dialer app when I click recent contact will show elevation layout and shrink margins?
I use `notifyitemchange`(position) and work in animate shift of point (left and top of layout).
but I want to animate shrink layout margins not shift view like google app dialer recent contacts [google app dialer].

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/groups_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="180dp"
           app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

viewholder layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="group"
            type="com.example.gtt.database.Group" />

        <variable
            name="clickListener"
            type="com.example.gtt.start.GroupListener" />

        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.example.gtt.start.StartViewModel" />

    </data>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        layoutMarginGroup="@{group}"
        layoutMarginGroupId="@{viewModel.hideShowId}"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="6dp">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/itemLayout"
            layoutBackColor="@{group}"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/cLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.onGroupHideShowClicked(group.groupId)}"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/groupView"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/layoutMargin"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/layoutMargin"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/layoutMargin"
                    android:background="@drawable/colored_circle"

                    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:onClick="@{() -> clickListener.onClick(group)}"
                    android:text="@{group.groupName.length >=2 ? group.groupName.substring(0,2).toUpperCase() :  group.groupName.toUpperCase() }"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/groupsTextView"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
                <!-- android:text="@string/g"    -->

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/groupsTextView"
                    groupNameText="@{group}"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBlue"
                    android:textSize="22sp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/materialTextView"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/cml"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/groupView"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/materialTextView"
                    groupMaterialText="@{group}"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBlue"
                    android:textSize="22sp"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/appTextView"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/groupsTextView"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/groupsTextView"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/groupsTextView" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/appTextView"
                    appText="@{group}"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBlue"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/groupsTextView"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/groupsTextView"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/materialTextView" />


                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/cml"
                    cmlBackColor="@{group}"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:minWidth="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/appTextView"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/groupsTextView"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                        android:paddingRight="10dp"
                        android:text="@string/numberOfClasses"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/classTextView"
                        classText="@{group}"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                        android:paddingRight="10dp"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorBlue"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                        android:paddingRight="10dp"
                        android:text="@string/numberOfMonths"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/monthTextView"
                        monthText="@{group}"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                        android:paddingRight="10dp"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorBlue"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/constraintLayout2"
                layoutVisibilityGroup="@{group}"
                layoutVisibilityGroupId="@{viewModel.hideShowId}"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/cLayout">
                <!--                android:visibility="gone"
                 android:background="@drawable/shadow_border"
                -->
                <View
                    android:id="@+id/divider9"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/addClassButton"
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_add_class"
                    android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.addClass()}"
                    android:text="@string/c"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/delClassButton"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/delClassButton"
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_del_class"
                    android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.delClass()}"
                    android:text="@string/c"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/addClassButton"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/addClassButton" />
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


</layout>
```

binding adapter to change data and layout

```
@BindingAdapter("layoutVisibilityGroup", "layoutVisibilityGroupId")
fun ConstraintLayout.setLayoutVisibility(item: Group, id: Long) {

    visibility = if (item.groupId == id) {
        View.VISIBLE
    } else {
        View.GONE
    }
}

@BindingAdapter("layoutMarginGroup","layoutMarginGroupId")
fun setLayoutMargin(view: CardView, item: Group, id: Long) {
    if (view.layoutParams is ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) {
        val p = view.layoutParams as ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams
        if (item.groupId == id) {
            val npx = dpToPixel(10f).toInt()
            p.setMargins(npx, p.topMargin, npx, p.bottomMargin)
        } else {
            p.setMargins(0, p.topMargin,0, p.bottomMargin)
        }
        //view.layoutParams = p
    }
    view.cardElevation = if (item.groupId == id) {
        dpToPixel(8f)
    } else {
        0f
    }
}
```

and I use this code to animate layout changes

```
 adapter.notifyItemChanged(oldPosition)
 adapter.notifyItemChanged(newPosition)
```

[image]

Comment: Please post code and layout you've tried.

Comment: Did you try anything with MotionLayout?

Comment: I Write the code that I used it please Help me Thanks @Daniel.Wang